# mobx-react-boilerplate @ unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I wanted to start new React project. I decided to use Mobx. I have found boilerplate that seemed to be perfect to use to start. I have fetched https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-boilerplate and I have encountered A problem. When I execute `npm start` occurs:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:2)

  2 | 
  3 | export default class TodoModel {
> 4 |   @observable title;
    |   ^
  5 |   @observable finished = false;
  6 | 
  7 |   constructor(title) {
```

How can I get rid of this problem? I thought that setup in this boilerplate would let me use `@observable`.

UPDATE

I have reinstalled the boilerplate and now I have another issue.

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (12:2)

  10 | 
  11 | render(
> 12 |   <div>
     |   ^
  13 |     <DevTools />
  14 |     <TodoList store={store} />
  15 |   </div>,
```

Comment: Do you have this plugin enabled? https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators

Comment: `mobx-react-boilerplate` should have [decorators enabled](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-boilerplate/blob/2461a87878b4aaefdf80e013df665bf50d09aaf7/.babelrc#L7). Try to remove `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: @Tholle I have just deleted `node_modules` and problem is still there. Any other ideas?

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński Then I don't know, I'm afraid. I just cloned the repository, ran `npm install`, `npm start`, and it worked for me.

Comment: @Tholle I have downloaded it once more and I have a different problem. Now after `npm install`, `npm start` I receive `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (12:2)` but this time the unexpected token is `<`in render method od index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this in your project first:

https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/tree/master/packages/react-app-rewire-mobx

and change your package.json

```
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build"
```